# treat specific warning as error Xcode

Tags: xcode, build-settings

In the Build Settings is it possible to treat Specific warnings as Error instead of Treating all warnings are Errors.

This is a simple Switch statement checker in xcode :

```
GCC_WARN_CHECK_SWITCH_STATEMENTS = YES_Error
```

**instead of :**

```
GCC_WARN_CHECK_SWITCH_STATEMENTS = YES
```

But its not working for me.

Answer (score 8):

### Treat specific warnings as errors

use `-Werror=`

for example:
`-Werror=unused-variable` will treat unused variable as error, which originally treat as warning by `-Wunused-variable` flag

add these to `Other Warning Flags` in project setting.

### Treat all warnings as errors except for some warnings

use `-Werror` and `-Wno-error=`

The first one will treat all warnings as errors, equals to the setting in Xcode.

And use `-Wno-error=` to make specific warning not be error. For example:
`-Wno-error=unused-variable`

add these to `Other Warning Flags` in project setting.

---

Reference https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

For all warning flags https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Answer (score 0):

This link may work for you.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html says

-Wno-error=switch makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect.

Please check.